# ERROR autenticacion asp.net MVC LoginViewModel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-4

tengo un proyecto con la autenticación de MVC, Con cuentas de usuarios individuales, pero le agregue la autenticación a través de un paquete nuget, todo iba bien hasta que las vistas comenzaron a darme error: el error es el siguiente en la vista Register y Login:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error dice:

> el nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres "RegisterViewModel" no se encotro (falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)

Comment: Hola, es mucho mejor que copies y pegues el código que una imagen, así podemos copiarlo y pegarlo para comprobar tu problema

Comment: ¿Dónde tienes definido RegisterViewModel?

Comment: Antes de usar el paquete de nuget funcionaba? o no lo ha hecho antes? según lo que comentas, tienes la clase AccountViewModel y dentro de esa clase RegistrerViewModel, la estructura para un ViewModel es: namespace { clase A, clase B, Clase C...} puede ser que no te lo esté detectando por eso. Cada modelo es una clase que estan en un Namespace, si lo tienes bien puedes usar @using AccountViewModels para forzar una carga en el cshtml y que lo coja

Comment: Lo que paso fue que cambie la base de datos de local a una que tengo en sql entonces el error comenzo ahí porque no encuentra esa clase

Comment: Eso no debería afectar a las vistas en nada, mira si `@model AccountViewModels.RegisterViewModel` funciona

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: no funciona :(  me da un error cuando le doy a enviar los datos del formulario de registro:   es el siguiente:  Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.

Detalles de la excepción: System.InvalidOperationException: No owin.Environment item was found in the context.

Error de código fuente:

el error me da en esta linea de codigo: 
         return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();